# Single use anonymous class in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, anonymous-class

I have a question about classes which sort-of relates to MVC because of the vast number of single-use models I seem to be creating.

I have an MVC Controller with a function that takes a model and returns an ActionResult. This model isn't going to be used anywhere else, so it feels like overkill to generate a specific class for it.

My question is this: Is there a way to specify that you'd like a model to match an anonymous type?

This contrived pseudocode (which does not work) shows what I mean:

```
Function ViewChanges(model As {.Comments as String, .ID as Integer}) As ActionResult
    'Do Some work...
End Function
```

Comment: MVC is language-agnostic design pattern. Seems that you are one of the people who refers to IE as "the internet" and to ASP.NET MVC framework as "mvc".

Comment: Good point. I shall change it.

Comment: @tereško That's nothing - where I work people say "I'll send you an Outlook." I wish I was joking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

But, you can still define a Structure:

```
Private Structure Model
    Dim Comments As String
    Dim ID As Int32
End Structure

Function ViewChanges(model As Model) As ActionResult
    'Do Some work...
End Function
```

Note that you can define it inside your class. You do not need to create an external class file.

This applies also to classes. You **can** define a class inside a class. But in this specific case, you can use a structure, that should be lighter than a class.

Comment: I thought that'd probably be the answer. Thanks. :)